# Nonetype object is not subscriptable, why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to recreate 2048 in python, but I'm having a problem with a function. It's supposed to compress the matrix to the left so that the matrix can be merged in the next step, but I keep getting a "Nonetype object is not subscriptable" error. I don't understand why this is happening, so I hope someone here can help. Code:

```
def compress(mat):
  changed = False
  new_mat = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
         
  for i in range(4):
    pos = 0
    for j in range(4):
      if(mat[i][j] != 0):
        new_mat[i][pos] = mat[i][j]      
        if(j != pos):
          changed = True
        pos=pos+1
  return new_mat, changed
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't showing enough of your code, so the only guess is that you pass a `None` into this function. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you include a full traceback, it will be possible to see not only that the error occurs, but where it occurs.

Comment: @Passerby haha you were right I forgot to add a return to a different function, it was passing None into the given one. Thanks!